# ODP.NET memory leak when using UDT:s

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net, user-defined-types

When using ODP.NET load data into and spatial database i'm using UDT to define the SDOGEOMETRY type.

Then i use the ArrayBindCount on the OracleCommand to load batches of data. Everything works, but i see a constant increase of memory of the process, and performance counters shows the same thing..

Parameter is created using:

```
var param = new OracleParameter("geom", OracleDbType.Object);
param.UdtTypeName = "MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY";
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Also, i set the cmd.AddToStatementCache = false to prevent data from ending up in there..

When adding data i use:
param.Value = new object[numRowsToInsert];

```
int row = 0;
foreach (var row in rowstoinsert)
{
  OracleUDT.SdoGeometry geoVal = rowstoinsert[row].geom;
  (param.Value as object[])[row] = geoval;
}
```

...

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   //THIS IS WHERE MEMORY LEAK APPEARS TO BE
```

..

I tried running the program with ExecuteNonQuery() removed, and then there is no MemoryLeakage at all....

**Edit:**
I also tried removing the UDT-parameter and run through the program, also without any leak. So it looks the problem is very close related to UDT:s and when statements are executed.

I'm using ODP.NET 11.2.0.2.1

Anyone got any clue?
Is there something i need to clean that does not get created if not running ExecuteNonQuery()?

Comment: The ExecuteNonQuery method does all the ADO.NET work (through the ODP.NET provider) so it makes sense that not executing would cause no leaks. Are you properly opening, closing and disposing the various ADO.NET objects (connection & command)?

Comment: I belive so, running the code WITH inserts but leaving out the UDT-columns (but keeping the other 17 columns) does not leak memory...

Commands are cleaned as:
cmd.Connection.PurgeStatementCache();
                            cmd.ArrayBindCount = 0;
                            for (int i = 0; i < cmd.Parameters.Count; i++)
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters[i].Value = null;
                                cmd.Parameters[i].Dispose();
                            }
                            cmd.Dispose();
                            cmd = null;

Comment: Sounds like you're doing the right things. The next step is to verify the memory leak in .NET using [WinDbg](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2007/11/13/getting-started-with-windbg-part-i.aspx). It is a pretty daunting tool to set up & use unfortunately. Create a memory dump of the app when it has leaked memory. After loading it in WinDbg and configured for .NET, run !dumpheap -type "UDT columnn type" where you use the actual ODP.NET type for the UDT columnn type. If a lot of instances pop up, then it's likely they're in a garbage collection root chain.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd give a followup on this one.
After numerous emails with Oracle Tech-Support i finally got this accepted as a bug

This appears to be Bug 10157396 which is fixed in 12.1, is planned to be fixed in 11.2.0.4 and has been backported to 11.2.0.2 (available in Patch Bundle 18). This can be downloaded from MyOracleSupport as Patches 10098816 (11.2.0.2) and 13897456 (Bundle 18) for a temporary solution while we get a backport to 11.2.0.3 or until 11.2.0.4 is released.